# SQL Server Order by Date then Group, but possible repeating group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in a SQL Server table

```
Date         Crew
==================
'2010-07-01',Crew1
'2010-07-02',Crew2
'2010-07-03',Crew2
'2010-07-04',Crew2
'2010-07-05',Crew1
'2010-07-06',Crew1
'2010-07-07',Crew1
'2010-07-08',Crew1
```

How I want to extract the data as is this

```
Date         Crew
==================
'2010-07-01',Crew1
'2010-07-02',Crew2
'2010-07-05',Crew1
```

i.e ordered by date, and then grouped by crew and showing the min(date), but note the repeating Crew1

So far all I can achieve is

```
Date         Crew
==================
'2010-07-01',Crew1
'2010-07-02',Crew2
```

How do i achieve what i want ? As when i try to group by crew and order by date it wont let me !

Comment: What about the date `'2010-07-31'` and `'2010-08-01'`??

Comment: Maybe i didnt explain well enough, if for example some more date were added like '2010-07-09','Crew3' and '2010-07-10','Crew1' I would expect to output of as I said above plus '2010-07-09','Crew3' and '2010-07-10','Crew1'.

Answer (score 2):

If you require the data with date<2014-07-31 thn use

```
 SELECT date, crew
   FROM table1
  WHERE date < '2010-07-31'
  GROUP BY date, crew
  ORDER BY date desc
```

else go for the below query. It'll sort the data as you require it to.

```
 SELECT date, crew
   FROM table1
  GROUP BY date, crew
  ORDER BY date desc
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d2dab/5)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you need the records of 2 minimum dates in your table. Please check my solution below.

If it doesnt meet your requirement then please comment

```
--Simulated your table
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    [DATE] DATETIME,
    CREW VARCHAR(50)
)

--Inserted values for testing
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], CREW) VALUES('2010-07-01','Crew1')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], CREW) VALUES('2010-07-02','Crew2')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], CREW) VALUES('2010-07-03','Crew2')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], CREW) VALUES('2010-07-04','Crew2')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], CREW) VALUES('2010-07-05','Crew1')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], CREW) VALUES('2010-07-06','Crew1')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], CREW) VALUES('2010-07-07','Crew1')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], CREW) VALUES('2010-07-08','Crew1')


--Your required query   
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT * FROM @tbl
    WHERE [DATE] IN (
        SELECT TOP 2 [DATE] FROM @tbl
        GROUP BY [DATE]
        ORDER BY [DATE] ASC
    )
    GROUP BY [DATE], CREW
)

SELECT * FROM MyCTE
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @tbl
WHERE CREW = 'Crew1'
AND [DATE] NOT IN
(
    SELECT [DATE] FROM MyCTE
)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but no, this will only ever get top 2

Comment: Check my updated answer. It doesnt look too elegant but it should give you the desired output and the best I could come up with right now

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
 SELECT date, crew
 FROM table1
 GROUP BY date, crew
```

Comment: No, that will just return everything

Answer (score 0):

isn't that so simple?

```
SELECT 
  MIN([DATE]) as [Date]
 ,CREW 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY CREW
ORDER BY Date ASC
```